# Are there different flavors of "REST"?

Tags: java, .net, rest, protocols

I work in Microsoft Stack company.  We have used REST on a few projects, so I know it works fine with Microsoft technologies.

But now we have an outside company making a REST Service for us.  This company does not use ANY Microsoft technologies. (They use Java mostly)

My understanding is that REST is a protocol and it should not matter what technology is used to build it.  Microsoft tools should be able to consume it.

But I usually confine my reading and learning to the Microsoft Stack, so I am not sure on this.  Can anyone who has experience in both Java and Microsoft let me know if REST Services from one and consumed by the other play well together?

Comment: REST is _not_ a protocol. It is an architectual style (read the Roy Fielding dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/fielding_dissertation.pdf) (PDF) for details.

Comment: @L.B - "YES" there are different flavors? or "YES" REST services from different stacks play well together?

Answer (score 3):

REST is an architectual style - it can be used with Java/.NET/Ruby/Whatever.

Written correctly, a REST API will be consumable by any modern language.